# to save data of two or more recycler view on one activity in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In an activity adding listing view on button click.

In the main view on saving click, I need to save all listing data same time.

this is my main view where adding the list

```
    <layout 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_text" android:id="@+id/mytool"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtMeal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Protocol is for"/>

                        <!-- <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/ivDelete"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:src="@drawable/iv_delete"
                             android:onClick="onClick"
                             android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />-->

                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_gradient"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

                        <!-- <TextView
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:background="@null"
                             android:paddingTop="5dp"
                             android:text="My self"
                             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                             android:paddingStart="15dp"
                             android:textSize="14sp"
                             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                             android:singleLine="true"
                             android:textColor="@color/white" />-->

                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:id="@+id/spinProtocol"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                        </Spinner>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Start date"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rlStartDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:onClick="onClick"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_gradient"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtStartDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="select date"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingStart="15dp"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imgProStartDate"
                            android:tint="@color/red"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                        </ImageView>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="End date"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rlEndDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:onClick="onClick"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_gradient"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtEndDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:text="end date"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:paddingStart="15dp"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                            android:id="@+id/imgProEndDate"
                            android:tint="@color/red"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                        </ImageView>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                    <!--Workout selected lisating -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/viewLayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnAddMeal"
                            android:layout_width="160dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:text="ADD MORE WORKOUT"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:onClick="onClick"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!--<LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/layout_workout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Workout Name: 1"
                                    android:id="@+id/workout_name"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>


                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/workout_name"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_white"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/ivDelelte"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                                android:background="@color/red">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                                    android:text="Excercise"
                                    android:layout_weight="2"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Sets"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Reps"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Rest(s)"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Temp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"/>


                            </LinearLayout>

                            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                tools:listitem="@layout/user_workout_list"
                                android:id="@+id/selected_excercise_list"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="+ Add Excercises"
                                android:id="@+id/add_excercise"
                                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/red"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>-->

                    <!--Workout name -->

           <!-- <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/viewLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                    </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnAddMeal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:text="ADD More WORKOUT"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/add"
                        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_gray_gredient"
                        android:onClick="onClick"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>-->

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/llDraft"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rect_border">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SAVE TO DRAFT"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llSave"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".50"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="onClick"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_red_gredient">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SAVE  "
                        android:fontFamily="@font/rubik_bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </layout>
```

And this is my listing view which I can add on button click maximum 5 views and now I need to save all listing data which added in the main view in android.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Workout Name 1"
                android:id="@+id/workout_name"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/workout_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_white"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivEdit"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/iv_delete"
                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:id="@+id/ivDelelte"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:background="@color/red">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="Excercise"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sets"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reps"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rest(s)"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Temp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/excercise_list"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+ Add Excercises"
            android:id="@+id/add_program_excercise"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your question is not understandable what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: in activity i can add two or more recycler view on button click as on add workout click now i want to save data of multiple recycler view list data on one activity

Comment: you want to show multiple recyclerview in one activity when you will click on the buttton, so for this you should add one or more recyclerview in activity

Comment: i done this with adding two or more view of listing my question is how to save data of that all recyclerview item listing data

Comment: your data is static or dynamics?

Comment: dynamic i am fetching data in recycler view from new activtiy list selected data items

Comment: you want to show that dynamic data that in every recyclerview? or on click you want to save that data on other recyclerview ___actually i m not understand to you what you want to say or do? you have to tell the step by step what you exactly looking for

Comment: i am getting dynamic data in all list in main view i like to get to know how to save all data from all listing items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207638/discussion-between-rachna-and-s-j).